# Cognito registration invite link instead of sending clear text password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Cognito sends the invitation emails to a user with a one time use password in clear text.
Is there a way to send a link instead of a clear text, where it redirects directly to the create new password section instead of asking again to login with temporary password.
If there is a way, please let me know the steps.
Thanks

Comment: You can customize your invitation mail and use the username and temp password as part of the invitation link. Then when the user clicks that link, on your invitation page automatically perform the initial login after which the user had to change his password

Comment: I have not found this customization for the 'invitation' message, but only for the 'verification' message... At the moment I am using the code, but, as stated, I can perform this choice only for the 'verification' message, i.e. when the registered user clicks on the 'forgot password'

Comment: @derpirscher I'm thinking of implementing your suggestion - but how can we include the temp password in the link without escaping it? The OTP can contain special characters like "/" and "?". I'm unaware of any way to escape it safely as part of the message template.

Comment: @ronrothman How are you creating the user? If you use `AdminCreateUser` you can specify the temporary password in the request. This way you could make it url safe ...

Comment: Got it, that should work - thanks!